# What are the potential causes of my fingers going numb when riding?

Tags: handlebars, health, adjustment

My fingers get numb quite quickly when riding. I'm a novice and not sure to what this can be due. I've tried gloves but they didn't help. I've tried added different handles to be able to switch positions more often; it helped a bit but it wasn't sufficient. I have an hybrid bike, a Minelli Revolution, if that changes anything. Currently looking to invest on a better bike though I'm afraid the issue will stick...

Are there specific adjustments on my bike that I should be tweaking to resolve this problem? It's really killing the joy of going for longer rides and I wish I could enjoy myself!

Comment: You need to start switching hand positions before the numbness starts, and ride one handed for a minute or so while flexing the free hand. See if that helps. How quickly is "quite quickly"? 5 minutes? 30 minutes?

Comment: If you can do it comfortably, you may try moving your saddle forward, this will give you a more upright position as you might be putting too much of your body weight on your hands.

Comment: Also, actively learning to put less weight on your hands.  Be aware, this will stress your core muscles and can be difficult to do for long periods of time, but does make for a great workout!

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest a change of gloves, but it seems that you already did so. If you haven't already, give a try to padded gloves.

You could try to check your grips and upgrade to ergonomic ones or changing the handlebar tape. Adjusting the saddle height might be a good idea too.

If the issue persists, perhaps the size of the handlebars or bike aren't adequate for your build, in which case you probably would benefit from getting a bike that fits you. See this [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5814/can-replacing-my-handlebar-tape-help-reduce-finger-numbness?rq=1) for additional suggestions.

As a last resort, and if you try all the possible adjustments, have a fitted bike, and still the numbness persists, I'd suggest you go to your doctor and discuss the issue.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a nice answer so I hope you hang around. You might like to take a look at the [tour] for a few tips on how to get the most out of the  site.