# Hand numb during sleep after training ride

Tags: fitness

After a hard training ride, I am more likely to wake in the night with my hand numb. This does happen at other times, but more often after a tough ride. I drag it around on the mattress to wake it up. Is there a nutrient I am missing?

Comment: Too much weight on your hands, plus you don't move them around enough when you ride.  I once had some gloves that helped this syndrome greatly, but, alas, they are no longer sold, and regular padded gloves do little for the condition.

Comment: Can you add a photo of a glove, showing the palm side ?

Comment: Frequent changes of position of the hands on the bar may help in your case.

Comment: wider tires might also increase comfort/reduce hand pain. If you are riding a mtb or hybrid you might consider installing (or upgrading if you already have it installed) your suspension. Cheap suspension forks are bad at reducing road vibration and can cause hand pain when going over bumpy roads/terrain.

Comment: This is probably the best post addressing your problem: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5814/can-replacing-my-handlebar-tape-help-reduce-finger-numbness/5822#5822

Answer (score 2):

Could be a number of things causing this, as others have mentioned in the comments just moving your hands around during the ride might be the fix.
You didn't mention what type of riding you're doing, but as someone who had similar concerns after a decent MTB ride (around 50km), here's a few things I did and was advised to try

1. Worked on using my core to hold me up rather than putting all that weight through my arms and hands
2. Got a set of ergo grips with a little "shelf" for the heal of my hand and take the weight off my palms
3. Got some small bar ends.  In the long haul part of the ride gave me more places to put my hands
4. Raise the handle bar.  Puts you into a more of an upright position so weight further back
5. Narrower bar, again as per above
6. Shorter Stem, as number 4

I did 2 & 3 while training myself to use my core.  Now I'm back on normal grips and as long as I remember to move my hands around, problem gone

Comment: Thanks. It's road cycling I'm doing. Moving my hands is probably wise. It's likely I'm just finding my old habits again after the winter. I'm still a little curious as to what has changed in the body, that only reveals itself hours later during sleep.

Comment: This may sound sarcastic but you're not sleeping on your hand / arm. Numbness would indicate a circulation problem which shouldn't occur at all. I sometimes find a little numbness in the fingers while riding, but a small adjustment from the hoods to the bars I find stops this. You shouldn't get any numbness from sleeping unless like I ask and you are sleeping on your hand without realising

Comment: @DanK.  Mine wasn't so much during sleeping, It was for a couple hours after the ride.  Apparently their is a number of nerve endings in and around your palm and I was just loading too much pressure on them for sustained periods